# Please filter sites by input as I type in search

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Maybe I'm so used to autocomplete/autofilter here on SE sites and on my phone that it just didn't occur to me that there were search paradigms that we used to have to live with.

I found it quite jarring to go into the list of all SE sites, type in a keyword that I knew was the name of a site... and nothing happened...

[image: not auto-filtering the list]

It turned out that I had to hit Enter on the keyboard to search, like in the old days!

Please either implement some sort of auto-search/filter as I type, or at the very least put a "Search" or "Go" type button in the UI on the input line to give a visible clue that I need to do something else after typing the search word in, so it's not too surprising when the page just sites there not reacting to my input.

Comment: Ugh, that's the old days? I *hate* search boxes that change the screen out from underneath me before I've submitted my query.

Comment: The question title is kind of misleading.

Comment: This is really a filter rather than a search, and while I am generally proud to count myself among the curmudgeons with Cody Gray, I have to agree with this request -- live _filtering_ is expected behavior.

Comment: I made some edits to your title, as what I read was completely different from what I expected after reading it. I think this better describes what you're trying to ask for, feel free to tweak as needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already planned, and I just checked it in. It will be in Version 0.1.4.

Comment: looking forward to it, thanks